# Partial applications and currying in functional programming

Tags: ocaml, currying

It's been hours and I can't understand this example in OCaml.

I don't know how to think about this so I'll try giving my process of thought.

The question is : **For each definition or expression, give the type and value (<fun> included)**

Here is the entire code (toplevel) :

```
let rec church_of_int n = 
    if n = 0 then fun f x -> x
    else fun f x -> church_of_int (n-1) f (f x);;

let three f x = church_of_int 3 f x;;

three (fun x -> x + 1) 0;;

three three (fun x -> x + 1) 0;;
```

### 1) First block

```
let rec church_of_int n = 
  if n = 0 then fun f x -> x
  else fun f x -> church_of_int (n-1) f (f x);;
```

This is a function which takes an int because of int operator "-" `n-1` and returns a function which takes two arguments 'a and 'b. The function returned returns the same type of 'b because of the `fun f x -> x`.

Therefore the type is :

```
int -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b = <fun>
```

But the toplevel says :

```
val church_of_int : int -> ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a = <fun>
```

I don't get it...

### 2) Second block

```
let three f x = church_of_int 3 f x;;
```

For the second block, three takes a function and an int and applies it to the returned function of church_of_int.

Therefore, the type is :

```
('a -> 'b) -> int -> 'b = <fun>
```

Toplevel says :

```
val three : ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a = <fun>
```

### 3) Third block

```
three (fun x -> x + 1) 0;;
```

Here, we apply a function and an int to three.

We need to compute

```
church_of_int 3 (fun x -> x + 1) 0

church_of_int 3 = fun f x -> church_of_int 2 f (f x)

church_of_int 2 = fun f x -> church_of_int 1 f (f x)

church_of_int 1 = fun f x -> church_of_int 0 f (f x)

church_of_int 0 = fun f x -> x
```

THEN

```
church_of_int 1 = fun f x -> ((fun f x -> x) f (f x)) = fun f x -> f x

church_of_int 2 = fun f x -> ((fun f x -> f x) f f(x)) = fun f x -> f (f x)

church_of_int 3 = fun f x -> ((fun f x -> f (f x)) f f(x)) = fun f x -> f (f (f x))
```

therefore,

```
church_of_int 3 (fun x -> x + 1) 0 = 3
```

Toplevel confirms this is correct.

### 4) Fourth block

```
three three (fun x -> x + 1) 0;;
```

Here it gets incredibly messy. On one side, we know that `three (fun x -> x + 1) 0 = 3`

then

three 3 is a partial application

on the other the toplevel returns 27.

Can you please help me fix my mistakes and my process of thought to get the correct types and results ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is a function which takes an `int` because of `int` operator "-" `n-1` and returns a function which takes two arguments 'a and 'b. The function returned returns the same type of 'b because of the `fun f x -> x`.
> Therefore the type is :

```
int -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b = <fun>
```

Let's look closer into the definition,

```
let rec church_of_int n = 
 if n = 0 then fun f x -> x
 else fun f x -> church_of_int (n-1) f (f x)
```

From the first branch of the `if` expression we indeed can infer that the return type is a function that takes two arguments and returns the last, i.e.,

```
int -> ('a -> 'b -> 'b)
```

which we can rewrite (using the right associativity of the `->` type operator as),

```
int -> 'a -> 'b -> 'b
```

Notice, how your train of thoughts diverged from the right path - as you represent a function that takes two arguments and returns the second as `('a -> 'b) -> 'b`. You placed parentheses incorrectly, in fact, your type represents a function that takes a single argument, which is itself a function that takes any argument and returns the value of type `'b`.

But let's go back to our definition. We used only the information from one branch of the `if` expression, so we missed some of the available information. From the `else` branch, `church_of_int (n-1) f (f x)` we can see that the first argument (which type we ascribed with `'a`) is a function itself, because of application `(f x)`, so we can refine `'a` to function type. We see that it is applied to `x`, which we know has type `'b`, moreover, the result of application is passed to the second parameter, which we inferred as `'b` from the first branch, so we know that the type of `f` is `'b -> 'b`. Now we substitute `'a` with `('b -> 'b)` and get,

```
int -> ('b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'b
```

which is equivalent modulo variable names to the type inferred by the OCaml toplevel.

So what does this type mean, or more specifically what does the `church_of_int n` expression define? This function applies `n` times the passed function `f` to the passed argument `x`. The type of the argument doesn't matter as we never use it, we just apply `f` to it `n` times.

With that knowledge we can easily digest `let three f x = church_of_int 3 f x`. It applies `f` to `x` three times. So the type is `('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a` (we still wait for `f` and `x` to be passed).

And if we pass `fun x -> x + 1` as the function and `0` as the initial value, then  `three (fun x -> x + 1) 0` is a three-fold application of that function to `0`. Let's name `fun x -> x + 1` as `succ`, so `three succ 0` is `succ (succ (succ 0)))`, i.e., a third successor of zero, which is three.

Now the hard part, let's try to understand the `three three (fun x -> x + 1) 0` expression. First of all, let's rewrite it as `three three succ 0`.

The first question that you might have is why `three` is able to accept more than two parameters? Since `three` has type `('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a` the second parameter `'a` could be a function itself. We know that `succ` has type `int -> int`, so we substitute `'a` with `(int -> int)`,

```
((int -> int) -> (int -> int)) -> (int -> int) -> (int -> int)
```

let's remove some parenthesis,

```
((int -> int) -> int -> int) -> (int -> int) -> int -> int
```

which gives us a function that takes three arguments,

- the function `three` with type `((int -> int) -> int -> int)`,
- the function `succ` with type `(int -> int)`
- the initial argument `0` with type `int`

And `three three succ` applies `three` three times to `succ`. So let's unfold it,

```
three three succ
===========================
three (three (three succ))
```

We already know that `three succ` adds `3` to the passed argument, so it is `x + 3`, let's name it `plus3` and rewrite,

```
three three succ
===========================
three (three (three succ))
=================== (three succ => plus3)
three (three plus3)
```

If we will repeat `plus3` three times, i.e., `x + 3 + 3 + 3` this is the same as `x + 9`, so we can rewrite it as,

```
three three succ
=========================== 
three (three (three succ))
=================== (three succ => plus3)
three (three plus3)
=================== (three plus3 => plus9)
three plus9
```

Now, the last step, repetition `x + 9 + 9 + 9` is `x+27`, so we can do the final rewrite,

```
three three succ
=========================== 
three (three (three succ))
=================== (three succ => plus3)
three (three plus3)
=================== (three plus3 => plus9)
three plus9
=========== (three plus9 => plus27)
plus27
```

so in the end `three three succ x` creates a function that is semantically equivalent to `fun x -> x + 27`, and `three three succ 0` gives us `27`.

Answer (score 2):

### For the first part

Let's just consider:

```
let rec church_of_int n =
    if n = 0 then fun f x -> x
    else fun f x -> church_of_int (n-1) f (f x)
```

What can we infer about types here?

Obviously, you've identified that `n` must be `int`, since it's both being subtracted and compared to another `int`.

```
int -> ... -> ... -> ...
```

As one example if we call `church_of_int 3` what does that look like? It returns a function that takes a function that takes a function `f` and a value `x`, which we denote as type `'a`. So `f` takes a value of type `'a` and turns it into...

Well, the result of `f x` is passed where `church_of_int` expects a value of type `a`, so the type of `f` must be `'a -> 'a`.

Now that we know the inferred types of `f` and `x`, we can finish the type signature of `church_of_int`.

```
int -> ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a
```

### Second block

With regards to:

```
let three f x = church_of_int 3 f x
```

This could just be the following using partial application.

```
let three = church_of_int 3
```

In this case the type signature `('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a` shouldn't be surprising.

### Third block

```
three (fun x -> x + 1) 0
```

Let's consider how this evaluates, with `(fun x -> x + 1)` subbed out for the partial application of the addition operator `((+) 1)`.

```
church_of_int 3 ((+) 1) 0
```

`3` doesn't equal `0` so we get back `fun f x -> church_of_int (n-1) f (f x)`, which we apply to `(3 - 1)`, `((+) 1)` and `((+) 1) 0`.

So now we've called:

```
church_of_int 2 ((+) 1) 1
```

Evaluate this and we get:

```
church_of_int 1 ((+) 1) 2
```

Since `1` isn't `0`:

```
church_of_int 0 ((+) 1) 3
```

Now, though, `n` *is* `0`, so we get a function where `f` is never applied to anything, so it doesn't matter. We just return `x`, which is `3`.

### Fourth part

Consider the definition of `three` again.

```
let three = church_of_int 3
```

The type is:

```
('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a
```

The first argument to `three` is a function that maps a value of type `'a` to another value of the same type. Let's rewrite that type signature a bit.

```
('a -> 'a) -> ('a -> 'a)
```

If we partially apply `three three` we get a function with the following type, which looks a lot like the type of `three`.

```
('_a -> '_a) -> '_a -> '_a
```

The effect of applying `three` to `three` is to get another function that takes a new function that takes a function and an initial value. We can apply this endlessly. Perhaps the syntax makes more sense if we look at it this way:

```
let f = ((+) 1 in
((three three) f) 0
```

And we can see this "exponentiation" by defining a few more functions.

```
─( 10:02:30 )─< command 42 >----
utop #
let two f x = church_of_int 2 f x
let three f x = church_of_int 3 f x
let four f x = church_of_int 4 f x;;
val two : ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a = <fun>
val three : ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a = <fun>
val four : ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a = <fun>
─( 10:02:39 )─< command 43 >----
utop #
let inc x = x + 1;;
val inc : int -> int = <fun>
─( 10:03:05 )─< command 44 >----
utop # two two inc 0;;
- : int = 4
─( 10:03:13 )─< command 45 >----
utop # two four inc 0;;
- : int = 16
─( 10:03:21 )─< command 46 >----
utop # two two two inc 0;;
- : int = 16
─( 10:03:30 )─< command 47 >----
utop # two two four inc 0;;
- : int = 256
```